# How to make custom spinner item with rounded icon image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

what I am trying to do is set a spinner list of items with a circle icon image to the left side of the text and once the item is selected the image will be a circle but filled with color.

I believe I have to implement an XML layout for the custom and an adapter holder to manage the icon change but I do not quite get it

is something like using

aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice)

but the icon is completely full with color and at the left side

Any help or suggestions would be great thanks.

i have created a mock class to fill the spinner adapter

```
class MockPoolName(val name: String, var isSelected: Boolean) {
}
```

then the spinner i have

```
poolNameAdapter = PoolNameAdapter(context!!, mockPoolList)
        sp_pools.adapter = poolNameAdapter
```

and the adapter class

```
class PoolNameAdapter(var context: Context, var countryNames: MutableList<MockPoolName>) :
    BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return countryNames.size
    }

    override fun getItem(i: Int): Any {
        return countryNames[i]
    }

    override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(i: Int, view: View, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
        var view = view
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, null)
        val icon: ImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.imgIcon) as ImageView
        val iconSelected: ImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.imgIconSelected) as ImageView
        val names = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtSpnPoolName) as TextView
        names.text = countryNames[i].name
        return view
    }

}
```

Custom spinner layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_oval_unselected"
                android:layout_marginStart="17dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIconSelected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_oval_selected"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSpnPoolName"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Pool"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/averta_semibold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You would have to create a custom spinner with custom layout to achieve this.

Comment: I have created the custom layout

Comment: Can you share code of how you are creating the spinner?

Comment: sure. I editted the question and put the code of what I have so far

Comment: I guess you forgot to add `custom_spinner_layout`. Could you also please add an image of how it looks now. I see that you have implemented a custom adapter which is what you need. But I don't get the problem you are facing. Is it regarding the color of circle when selected?

Comment: I get an error when running
Process: com.alicorp.android.nicosoft.qa, PID: 19042
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter view
        at com.alicorp.android.nicosoft.presentation.chief_technician.results.comparative.adapter.PoolNameAdapter.getView(Unknown Source:2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239148/discussion-between-akhil-nair-and-alejandro-vargas).